# jQuery nextUntil() stops at closing tag

Tags: jquery, dom, select

I am trying to grab all the td elements between the first two that have the class 'selected'. and change the text color to green. I am using nextUntil but the problem I am facing is that when there is a new `<tr>` it doesn't grab those td elements. Is there a way to ignore any `<tr>` tags using nextUntil? Thanks

jQuery:

```
var firstDate = $('table.jCalendar tbody').find($('td.selected')[0]);
var secondDate = $('table.jCalendar tbody').find($('td.selected')[1]);
$(firstDate).nextUntil(secondDate).css("color", "green");
```

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="2" class="jCalendar"><tbody>
<tr>
   <td class="current-month weekday today unselectable">18</td>
   <td class="current-month weekday unselectable">19</td>
   <td class="current-month weekday selected">20</td>
   <td class="current-month weekday unselectable" style="color: green; ">21</td>
   <td class="current-month weekday unselectable" style="color: green; ">22</td>
   <td class="current-month weekend unselectable" style="color: green; ">23</td>
   <td class="current-month weekend unselectable" style="color: green; ">24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="current-month weekday today unselectable">25</td>
   <td class="current-month weekday unselectable">26</td>
   <td class="current-month weekday selected">27</td>
   <td class="current-month weekday unselectable">28</td>
   <td class="current-month weekday unselectable">29</td>
   <td class="current-month weekend unselectable">30</td>
   <td class="current-month weekend unselectable">31</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

so to clarify i want the td elements with the texts 20 through 26 selected but 21 through 24 is only being selected. Sometimes there are more then just one set of `<tr>` tags between the td tags with the class selected.

Comment: `.nextUntil(` check `siblings` only. `25,26` aren't siblings of first `.selected`.

Comment: Are they always layed out consecutive in rows with the same number of td's in each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is to highlight every TD regardless of row between the 2 selected class.

Am using a class change instead of inline CSS as it is much easier to remove on subsequent selections with one line of code.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/5txeq/

```
var firstRow = $('td.selected:first').parent()
var secondRow = $('td.selected:last').parent();

$('tr').slice(firstRow.index() + 1, secondRow.index()).find('td').addClass('green')

firstRow.find('.selected').nextAll().andSelf().addClass('green')
secondRow.find('.selected').prevAll().andSelf().addClass('green')
```

Alternate  shorter version:
DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/5txeq/2/

```
var $cells = $('tbody td'),
    idx_1 = $cells.index($('td.selected:first')),
    idx_2 = $cells.index($('td.selected:last'));

$cells.slice(idx_1, idx_2 + 1).addClass('green');
```

Comment: if need to adjust so green class doesn't conflict with selected class, just adjust the 2 index variables in slice()

Answer (score 0):

Not really; that's how `nextUntil` is designed. You'll need to create an `each` loop that runs through all the `<td>` tags in order:

```
var color_it = false;
$('table.jCalendar tbody').find('td').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if $this.is(firstDate) {
        color_it = true;
    };
    if $this.is(secondDate) {
        color_it = false;
    };
    if (color_it) {
        $this.css("color", "green");
    };
});
```

For what it's worth, you could also replace your table cells with `<div>` tags which have `display: table-cell;` styles attached. Then they would all be siblings. However, [this isn't supported in older browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html).

Answer (score 0):

In this method you select all the cells and filter out the ones before and after the selection

```
var selectStart = false;
$('table.jCalendar td').not(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        selectStart = !selectStart;
    }
    return !selectStart;
}).css({color:'green'});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/FMq2D/)